# Azure AD Authentication remove the saved user credential

Tags: windows, azure, authentication, uwp, azure-active-directory

In My UWP application I have added Azure AD authentication for users.The users can signed in properly.However once the Stay signed in option is ticked by a user the next time just by clicking the login button the user can get logged in.Where those user credential get saved in the device.From where can I remove the saved user and login as another user?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `microsoft.identity.client`, then you can access the accounts information by calling the method `GetAccountsAsync()` which returns a list of all the accounts that have an active token stored in the client

To access the token stored you can call the method `AcquireTokenSilent()` and then parse the token string to get the actual data using a library such as `System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt`:

```cs
var accounts = await app.GetAccountsAsync();

AuthenticationResult result = null;
try
{
     result = await app.AcquireTokenSilent(scopes, accounts.FirstOrDefault())
                       .ExecuteAsync();
}
catch (MsalUiRequiredException ex)
{
    // A MsalUiRequiredException happened on AcquireTokenSilent.
    // This indicates you need to call AcquireTokenInteractive to acquire a token
    Debug.WriteLine($"MsalUiRequiredException: {ex.Message}");

    try
    {
        result = await app.AcquireTokenInteractive(scopes)
                          .ExecuteAsync();
    }
    catch (MsalException msalex)
    {
        ResultText.Text = $"Error Acquiring Token:{System.Environment.NewLine}{msalex}";
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    ResultText.Text = $"Error Acquiring Token Silently:{System.Environment.NewLine}{ex}";
    return;
}

if (result != null)
{
    string accessToken = result.AccessToken;
    // Use the token
}
```

To remove the token stored in cache you can refer to this documentation : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-net-acquire-token-silently#clearing-the-cache

Comment: But I want to stay signed in when the user click signed in button. If the user prefers to login as another user only want to remove the saved credentials. And I want to it without any code changes